# Vue.js app throws error "Cannot find element: #app"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently using Webpack as a build system and have set up everything properly so that it was working well.

All of the sudden, it started giving me an error stating:

> [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

I tried running the `beforeCreated()` hook on the root instance itself, where if the element does not exist I manually create it. But to no avail.

I have uploaded my code to Gitub, with a `package.json` file. It would be really amazing if someone can take a look and provide a solution.

I went spend hours going trough the code and even removed all other dependencies, but the most basic configurations, changed the import order and it still doesn't work.

Here is the link to the Github repo: [Github](https://github.com/YYonkov/twp)

Comment: The [code that created the `#app` div is commented out](https://github.com/YYonkov/twp/blob/17e41b25e52cee2ba0d4e2ff4dbac24956a172cf/src/main.js#L12-L17) right now.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work with it either. The element exists in a component which is imported prior to the Vue instance

Comment: Either you create the element before and mount the vue after, or you put a `<div id="app"></div>` in the index.html before the js bundle.

Comment: I downvoted because questions seeking debugging help should have a [mcve] in the question itself. The comment was just to try and help anyway.

Comment: [Relevant canonical question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1218980)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a `#app` element in the index.html to mount the app:

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that Vue cannot be mounted on <html> or <body> it has to use another element